# mkpath failing if directory already exists?

Tags: windows, perl

I'm trying to debug a problem on a friend's machine.
I wrote a script to copy over some files and the script makes use of [mkpath](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) (I know mkpath is decrepit and now there is make_path, but I'm using an older version of perl).

On my machine (with the **same** version of perl and operating system etc..) the script runs fine even under the conditions where the directories already exist.

However,

When I try running the script on my friend's machine, mkpath throws an error when being called on directories that already exist!

The error it throws is 'mkdir  : File exists'

I'm pretty stumped as to why the script works on my machine but not his.

Thanks
Farid

## EDIT ADDING MORE USEFUL INFO

Okay, so here are a few more things to help diagnose this problem

1. We are using the same version of Perl and File. Both are stored on a Perforce repository so we are 100% using the same version
2. I am copying the files to a network shared system. Therefore the filepath is of the type: `\\NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2/Directory3`
3. The script loops through a bunch of files and copies them over. The **first** file is **always** successfully copied, however on the 2nd file it fails with the error

   mkdir \NETWORK-COMP/Directory1 File exists

Directory1 is not a file and it is in fact a GUID and there are no collisions (I double checked every time)!

Comment: Are you using the same version of File::Path on both machines?

Comment: Are they not based on the version of Perl? We're using the same version of perl

Comment: [File-Path](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path/) is a dual-lived distribution, so it can be upgraded independently of `perl`.

Comment: I am sourcing Perl from a repository (Perforce) and we are both synced to the same repository and verion

Comment: `mkdir \NET...` is missing a `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that part of the path exists, but it's not a directory.

```
$ echo foo >foo

$ perl -MFile::Path -e'mkpath "foo"'
mkdir foo: File exists at -e line 1
```

---

Another possibility is that the two machines have different versions of File::Path, and one has a bug in it. If so, you could just upgrade [File-Path](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path/).

---

A third possibility is that you're giving bad input on one of the machines. I get

```
mkdir PATH: File exists
```

but you get

```
mkdir : File exists
```

It could be because of a difference in version, but I don't think so because of the space before the "`:`". Check your input using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) (after doing `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;`) to make sure you are passing what you think you are passing.

Comment: I am sourcing Perl from a repository (Perforce) and we are both synced to the same repository and verion

Comment: @Setheron, how about the other possible reason I gave?

Comment: @Setheron, added a third possible reason.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting mkdir PATH: File exists, but why would it be working on my machine and not my friends? It's worth noting that the file is on a network machine

Comment: so the directory is something like : "\\NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2"

Comment: It fails on Directory1 however Directory1 is a GUI so there is no collision (I checked) and no file named that GUID as well!

Comment: One more edit: It fails on the 2nd attempt, I'll add this all to my question!

Comment: @Setheron, `"\\NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2"` produces the string `\NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2` (note the single leading `\ `). If you actually have that in your code, you want `"\\\\NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2"` or `"//NETWORK-COMP/Directory1/Directory2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Same OS? Same version of Perl? Hmm....

I've seen this error message when there's an existing file in the path it's trying to create. For example, I try to create the directory `foo/bar/bar/foo`, but there's a file `foo/bar/bar`, the `mkpath` will fail with the error message you said.

Is it possible that this was the case? Try this small test program on your computer:

Run the following command on both systems:

```
$ perldoc -lm File::Path
```

This will print out the *location* of the File::Path module that's being included. My suspicion is that you're not executing the File::Path module you think you are.

After you determine the actual modules being used, check to see if the two modules agree. Also, while you're at it, do a `perl -V` (that's a capital `V`). That will give you a lot of information about your Perl installations including libpath, posix is used. It's very possible that you compiled the Perl with the same source code, but the compile flags differed.

Try this test program on both system:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;

open (FOO, ">foo") or die qq(Things really aren't going your way\n);
print FOO "THIS\n";
close FOO;

if (my $value = mkpath "foo/foo/bar/foo") {
    print "It worked: $value !\n";
} else {
    print "It didn't: $value !\n";
}
print "And the program continues\n";
```

This **should** fail because I'm creating a file `foo` and then trying to make a path `foo/boo/bar/foo`. In fact, I get the following error:

```
mkdir foo: File exists at ./test.pl line 11
```

One of these things will give us a clue what's going on.

Comment: awesome. I'll try these things Tuesday ! (Monday is labour day) =)